# How to know if phone call is on process

Tags: android, google-glass

I need to know from glass, if there is a phone call in process. I can made it easy on android device ... but I have problems with glass, the same code to telephonymanager and so on ... doesn't works on glass.

Any idea how to catch the broadcasting process or PhoneCallManager to know if the phone has is talking?

thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Glass works as a bluetooth headset when making a phone call (see [user guide](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3085955?hl=en-GB)). It is not making the calls itself.

I think you'll have to use the [BluetoothHeadset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) class which will allow you to interact with the Headset bluetooth profile. You can then retrieve the state of the headset connection.